# How to add values to another table's value by MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm a newbie about SQL triggers. I'm trying to create a trigger when a row inserted to `actions` table, it should get the `accounts` table's matched `account_id` and update its `value` by adding to `value`.

Accounts table:

```
+------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value               |
+------------------+---------------------+
| account_id       | 1                   |
| value            | 100                 |
+------------------+---------------------+
```

Inserted row to actions table:

```
+------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value               |
+------------------+---------------------+
| account_id       | 1                   |
| value            | 10                  |
+------------------+---------------------+
```

I'm trying to make this situation: When inserted to `actions` with value 10, the row which has 1 `account_id` in the `accounts` table, it's `value` must be **110**.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simple update statement like so.

```
UPDATE accounts SET `value` = `value` + 10 WHERE account_id = 1
```

How we can do that using trigger. We will pick `account_id` and `value` from `actions` table using `NEW` keyword and use in this query.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `actions_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `actions` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE accounts
    SET `value` = `value` + NEW.`value`
    WHERE account_id = NEW.account_id;
END

$$
```

Comment: @sundowatch, does it worked for you. If so, don't forget to vpvote & accept the answer